# checking edittext text always return false

Tags: java, android

im trying to get text from edit text and check if it is True or False and if not display an error message

```
        correcttxt=correctans.getText().toString();

 if ((!correcttxt.equals("True")) || (!correcttxt.equals("False"))){
            AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder=new AlertDialog.Builder(AdminAdd4.this);
            alertBuilder.setTitle("Invalid");
            alertBuilder.setMessage("The correct answer should be True or False.");
            alertBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            alertBuilder.create().show();
        }
    else {
                //confirmation to add exercise
                AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder=new AlertDialog.Builder(AdminAdd4.this);
                alertBuilder.setTitle("Add Exercise");
                alertBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to add this exercise?");
                alertBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    new CreateNewexercise().execute();

                    }
                });
                alertBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                alertBuilder.create().show();
            }
```

but this will always display the error message even when the text is True or False i don't know why ?

can someone help please ? thank you :)

Comment: You want `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: @MikeM. yess omg stupid me! THANK YOU SO MUCH !!